# Linq to CSV : Convert data to .CSV file and return file from an action without saving file on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, csv, linqtocsv

I am [LinqToCsv](http://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToCsv) and this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library) to convert my data to a downloadable csv files.

**WHAT HAVE I DONE :**

I have created an action like the one shown below:

```
public FileResult GetReportCsvData(MyFilterModel model)
{
    var data = _myService.GetMyData(model);

    var fileName = String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2:yyyy_MMM_d}", Helpers.GetLoggedInUserName(), "Ad-Reports", DateTime.Today) + ".csv";
    var outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription { SeparatorChar = ',', FirstLineHasColumnNames = true };
    
    var cc = new CsvContext();
    cc.Write(data, "c:/" + fileName, outputFileDescription);

    return File("c:/" + fileName, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

and using the following jquery I get my csv file:

```
exportCsv: function () {
    var data = this.getFilters();
    var url = '/MyController/GetReportCsvData';
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.action = url;
    form.method = 'POST';
    form.style.display = 'none';        
    for (i in data) {
        if (data[i] != "") {
            var inputElement = document.createElement('textarea');
            inputElement.name = i;
            inputElement.value = data[i];
            form.appendChild(inputElement);
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

This works and I get the csv file with the download prompt.

**WHAT DO I WANT**

Here with the current code I have to save the file on my server (C:/filename) and then return its File object.

I do not want to save it on my server.

What changes do I have to make to achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

on "cc.Write" you write to disk, outputFileDescription is already a TextStream. So instead of saving it to disk first, and then reading it from disk with "File", just return the TextStream

Comment: @Kodefoo Why? Google can serve up 10's of thousands of examples on how to read a textstream without saving it to disk first and reading it from disk again?

Comment: Then it should be no problem for you to add to your answer and make it that much more helpful to other people who end up here from a google search.